# Change RingCentral behavior in Salesforce App

Tags: salesforce, ringcentral

We've recently integrated the RingCentral app with our Salesforce org, and we'd like to change the behavior of how calls are logged. The calls in question are related to phone numbers attached to Opportunities.

From what we can tell, the app only permits you to log a call made with this method as a new task under the associated Account, if an Account exists.

- We want calls from the logged as a "Log a Call" record under the Opportunity, not as a Task under the Account.
- We'd also like to be able to call from and log against an existing Task in certain cases. For example, there may be a Task to follow up on a stalled opportunity, and an outgoing call can log against that task.

I don't think this functionality is possible natively, and I'm pretty new to the RingCentral API. Is it possible to achieve this functionality through the API and Salesforce somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the behavior of RingCentral in Salesforce by using the Embeddable Voice Widget:

[Embeddable Voice Widget](https://developer.ringcentral.com/embeddable-voice.html)

- https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable-voice

There are a series of demos here:

- https://github.com/ringcentral-tutorials/ringcentral-web-widget-demos

Specific Salesforce demos include:

- [`salesforce_lightning/tutorial`](http://ringcentral-web-widget-demos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/salesforce_lightning/tutorial/) - basic embedding in Salesforce
- [`salesforce_lightning_more/tutorial`](http://ringcentral-web-widget-demos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/salesforce_lightning_more/tutorial/) - shows how to customize the experience

See discussion on getting objectId for object that triggered widget:

- https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable-voice/issues/112

Comment: Thanks for this; on the tutorial, under "Create a RingCentral App", where is the menu to do this? Do you mean a new Lightning App, or something else? I don't see those configuration options (Platform Type, Grant Types, Permissions) anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Create this app by logging into RingCentral Developers - https://developer.ringcentral.com. If you are a RingCentral customer, you can likely just log in.

Comment: Is there any way for me to determine the ID of the object (i.e. an Opportunity, task, etc.) which triggered the widget activation? Otherwise I don't think the customization will be useful. I need to assign the task to a specific Opportunity.

Comment: For that question, you should reach out to the developers directly on the GitHub repo here: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable-voice/issues

Comment: Turns out there's a way to access the recordId as part of [the OpenCTI methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_onclicktodial_lex.htm). This works great. Thank you!